# Choose which result comes first in MySQL result set

Tags: mysql, activerecord

I'm pulling a list of counties and need to be able to specify which one will go first in the result set depending on the url. The remaining counties can be in whatever order. I don't know the county ids beforehand I just know that they are in a specific state. For example:

> nj/county/bergen

should pull up

> Bergen
>
> Passaic
>
> Essex
>
> Morris
>
> Sussex
>
> Hudson
>
> Union
>
> etc

---

> nj/county/morris

should pull up

> Morris
>
> Passaic
>
> Essex
>
> Bergen
>
> Sussex
>
> Hudson
>
> Union
>
> etc

and so on, and so forth.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Agree with @JohnConde - more detail and what you have tried will get you better answers.

Comment: Sorry, the only thing I tried was 2 separate queries. I thought about using ORDER BY FIELD, but I don't think I can do a "wildcard" there like ORDER BY FIELD (county,Bergen,%) % meaning all the rest.

Comment: Does the revised answer work for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2** Removed earlier answers as they add little value.

Debugged query:

```
SELECT * from counties ORDER BY county like 'Essex' DESC, county ASC
```

Reason this works: The `county like 'Essex'` evaluates to true/false or more specifically: 1 or 0. I sort these descending and the matches (1's) will be on top, anything that doesn't match (0's) is on bottom. The second ORDER BY field just ensures the rest of the list is in alphabetical order.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a738/5

For posterity here is the table I used:

```
CREATE TABLE counties 
(
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 county varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO counties
(county)
VALUES
('Bergen'),('Passaic'),('Essex'),('Morris'),('Sussex'),('Hudson');
```